# TreeView Doesn't Display Last Node

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have a TreeView that I populate basically like this

```
For Each s As Store In storeList
    Dim n As TreeNode = Nothing
    n = New TreeNode(s.StoreName) With {.Name = s.StoreID, .Tag = s}
    tvStores.Nodes.Add(n)       
Next
```

This works perfectly fine normally, but one of our customers has found that it won't add the LAST added node into the list. For example, if we have 100 elements, it will add all 100, but only display 99. I'm able to step through code and see the final one added to the treeview, but it still doesn't display.

I've tried using a smaller list, a larger list, different items, but it still won't show up. This method works for 999 of our 1000 users, it's just one this one location where it won't show up. Any advice on even troubleshooting? I mean it pulls back all the correct values from SQL, runs through each of them in the for loop, gets to the 'add' with no issues and then it just disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this:

```
tvStores.BeginUpdate()
For Each s As Store In storeList
   Dim n As TreeNode = Nothing
   n = New TreeNode(s.StoreName) With {.Name = s.StoreID, .Tag = s}
   tvStores.Nodes.Add(n)       
Next
tvStores.EndUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the following block at the end of your loop

```
Dim lastNode as TreeNode
'
lastNode = tvStores.Nodes(tvStores.Nodes.Count - 1)
If Not lastNode.IsVisible Then lastNode.EnsureVisible()
```